# Javascript function not working inside composite control JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a composite control as below;

> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
>         xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="validatorId"/>
    <composite:attribute name="message"/>        
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div>                   
        <script type="text/javascript">
             function #{cc.attrs.validatorId}(){alert('why is it not working :(');};
        </script>                                
        <div style="background-color: #F2DEDE;color: #b94a48;border-style: solid;border-color: #FAC3CB;border-width: 1.8px;font-family: Arial;
              font-size: 12px;height:17px;vertical-align: middle;padding-left: 8px;padding-right: 8px;padding-top: 2px;display: none;"
              id="#{cc.attrs.validatorId}">
            #{cc.attrs.message}
            <img src="images/close-mini.png" style="cursor: pointer;padding-left: 5px;"/>            
        </div>
    </div>
</composite:implementation> </html>
```

This control is placed in a xhtml file.The javascript and composite controls are rendering as the expected way. But when a request is made to xhtml following exception occurs at Glassfish Server :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed.

What can be the reason? When I remove the javascript function exception doesn't occurs.

Comment: Can you include whole stacktrace?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+create+a+session+after+the+response+has+been+committed. That it happened when you added JS code is pure coincidence. It would also happen when you add the same amount of bytes of plain HTML or even plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following prerender listener is added at composite control,

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{fieldValidatorBean.PreRenderValidator}"/>
```

and inside the listener function,

```
 public void PreRenderValidator(){
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
     System.out.println("prerender being called");
}
```

to reenable session. Thanks @BalusC.